# Python progress bar on server for each user

Tags: python, webserver

I'm trying to implement a feature like this:

I would running a server, and then the users would come to the server and submit their jobs(I just need to run the jobs sequentially). Each job would take a long time to complete, and there are lots of status (like how many tweets downloaded already etc.) for each job, and I wish to present the status to the users. I'm implementing the job objects as a class, i.e.

```
Class Job:
   def __init__():
      initial status
   def do_download():
      do download 
   def report_status():
      return [self.tweets_downloaded, self.bad_tweets...]
```

However, I'm kind of trapped here because I can't call 'report_status()' while the server is running `do_download()`. Anybody has any suggestions? I appreciate it.

I ended up with using a thread to execute the "do_download" function. And in main thread just call "report_status" it would give me the status of how the job was doing.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) or another task queuing system.  All of your jobs will be run in separate processes (no worrying about thread safety or the GIL) and can update a central data store with progress as often as you want.

Comment: Thx Andrew. I tried to use Celery but it seems too heavy for my little task : )

Comment: Okay, but be aware that your task may be deceptively complex!

Answer (score 0):

do your long running job in a Thread that updates some status.txt file that you scan in report_status

Comment: That's almost what I did after searching a while. I used a separate thread to launch a class method, and the status are kept in the class as class variables. So that I could call another class method called "report" in the main thread to reporting the status. Thank you very much Joran